# using ActionBar, How and when onPrepareOptionsMenu() invoked?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How and when overridden method **onPrepareOptionsMenu()** called ?

i have seen, **onPrepareOptionsMenu()** will be called automatically after **onCreateOptionsMenu()**.

And if i called **invalidateOptionsMenu()** on any action-item click event, then , it will be called like ,

**onPrepareOptionsMenu() -> onCreateOptionsMenu() -> onPrepareOptionsMenu()**

Why onPrepareOptionsMenu() is called twice ?

And

My question is how to update ActionBar item at Runtime, on two different action-item click event ?  Otherwise it is called same implementation as written with in onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Android 3.0+ the Action Bar forces the options menu to be built early so that items chosen to show as actions may be displayed when the activity first becomes visible. The Activity method invalidateOptionsMenu forces the entire menu to be destroyed and recreated from onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu), offering a similar though heavier-weight opportunity to change the menu's contents. Normally this functionality is used to support a changing configuration of Fragments.

You can call `invalidateOptionsMenu` to recreate actionbar menu if you want to change/update actionbar menu items, such as make some menu item `VISIBLE/INVISIBLE`.

Comment: Two things ,( 1 ) onCreateOptionsMenu is only called once, as per document.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29          ( 2 ) How to use onPrepareOptionsMenu , for more than one Dynamic content.

Comment: @sandeepgupta Yes that's true, but `invalidateOptionsMenu` force to recreate menu again.

Comment: How to use onPrepareOptionsMenu , for more than one Dynamic content ?

Comment: In my case, I have many items in menu, then I choose which item show for different fragments, and I have some flags to tell `onPrepareOptionsMenu` which show or not

Answer (score 0):

in my case , i want to load dynamic content for more than one Action-item click event. No need to override onPrepareOptionsMenu(), instead i have instantiating flag value on onOptionsItemSelected  and called invalidateOptionsMenu , So it will call  onCreateOptionsMenu on every occurrence of invalidateOptionsMenu. And make conditions accordingly in onCreateOptionsMenu.This solved the issue.